# What exactly is a dummy trap? Is dropping one dummy feature really a good practice?

Tags: one-hot-encoding, dummy-variables

So I'm going through a Machine Learning course, and this course explains that to avoid the dummy trap, a common practice is to drop one column. It also explains that since the info on the dropped column can be inferred from the other columns, we don't really lose anything by doing that.

This course does not explain what the dummy trap exactly is, however. Neither it gives any examples on how the trap manifests itself. At first I assumed that dummy trap simply makes the model performance less accurate due to multicollinearity. But then I read [this article](https://inmachineswetrust.com/posts/drop-first-columns/). It does not mention dummy trap explicitly, but it does discuss how an attempt to use OHE with OLS results in an error (since the model attempts to invert a singular matrix). Then it shows how the practice of dropping one dummy feature fixes this. But then it goes on to demonstrate that this measure is unnecessary in practical cases, as apparently regularization fixes this issue just as well, and algorithms that are iterative (as opposed to closed-form solution) don't have this issue in the first place.

So I'm confused right now in regards to what exactly stands behind the term "dummy trap". Does it refer specifically to this matrix inversion error? Or is it just an effect that allows the model to get trained but makes its performance worse, and the issue described in that article is totally unrelated? I tried training an sklearn LinearRegression model on a OHE-encoded dataset (I used `pd.get_dummies()` with the `drop_first=False` parameter) to try to reproduce the dummy trap, and the latter seems to be the case: the model got trained successfully, but its performance was noticeably worse compared to the identical model trained on the set with `drop_first=True`. But I'm still confused about why my model got successfully trained at all, since if the article is to be believed, the inversion error should have prevented it from being successfully trained.

Comment: https://datascience.stackexchange.com/a/85000/106732

Comment: @ShahriyarMammadli yes, I'm aware that not removing one dummy feature will result in multicollinearity of these features, which in turn will result in false parameters. However, the article I linked seems to imply that even if we do remove one dummy feature, it will still result in false parameters, because we can get vastly different results depending on which exact dummy feature we drop. Have you read this article? Do you have anything to say in regards to whether the dummy trap has anything to do with the matrix inversion error?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two main problems -

1. You have one Feature which is correlated (*multi-collinearity)* to all the others.
2. **If you are trying to solve using** "*closed-form solution*", the following will happen

$y = w_0 + w_1X_1 + w_2X_2 + w_3X_3$

$w_0$ is the $y$ intercept and to complete the matrix form 1=$X_0$. Hence,

$y = w_0X_0 + w_1X_1 + w_2X_2 + w_3X_3$

Solution for $w$ is $(X^{T}X)^{-1}X^{T}y$

So, X must be an Invertible Matrix. But,

*If the model contains dummy variables for all values, then the encoded columns would add up (row-wise) to the intercept ($X_0$ here)(See below table) and this linear combination would prevent the matrix inverse from being computed (as it is singular).*

\begin{array} {|r|r|}
\hline
X_0 & X1 &X2 &X3 \\
\hline
1 &1 &0 &0 \\
\hline
1 &0 &1 &0 \\
\hline
1 &0 &0 &1 \\
\hline
\end{array}

> *why my model got successfully trained at all since if the article is to be believed, the transposition error should have prevented it from being successfully trained.*

Valid question! Aurelien Geron(Author of "*Hands-On Machine Learning*" has answered [Here](https://github.com/ageron/handson-ml/issues/167).

- *The LinearRegression(Scikit-Learn) class actually performs SVD decomposition, it does not directly try to compute the inverse of X.T.dot(X). The singular values of X are available in the singular_ instance variable, and the rank of X is available as rank_*

#### On Performance

- In a practically large dataset, *a closed-form solution is not preferred.* May use
  an Iterative approach algorithm *i.e. Gradient-Descent*
- Multi-collinearity too, *will not impact the performance* but Interpretability of Features.
- *Coeff changes depending upon which dummy is removed* - This is obvious as each dummy is now a Feature with a different level of contribution *(based on data)*. The only thing that is sure is their effect together and one-less is the same.
- **The inconsistent result** you are getting should be due to some other issue.

> Dummy-variable Trap

I have never heard of this term except "*Udemy course A-Z ML*". So I don't think that there is any special meaning of the word *"trap"* if you understand the points(*i.e. Singularity, Multi-collinearity, and Interpretability)* separately

References -

[www.feat.engineering - Sec#5.1](http://www.feat.engineering/creating-dummy-variables-for-unordered-categories.html)

[Sebastian Raschka](https://sebastianraschka.com/faq/docs/closed-form-vs-gd.html)

[stats.stackexchange](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/23128/solving-for-regression-parameters-in-closed-form-vs-gradient-descent/23132#23132)

Comment: So basically, problem 2 is irrelevant for the scikit-learn implementation, I see. Problem 1 (interpretability) appears to be less trivial, and certainly not as straightforward as most articles on this topic seem to imply. Thank you for references, your first link provides some insight into how dummy features are supposed to be interpreted. It looks like whatever dummy feature we drop becomes a "reference cell", and its importance is conveyed through the intercept, while parameters of dummy features add to/subtract from that reference cell importance, rather than being independent importances.

Comment: But the above is the case only when we have one categorical variable. When we have several, that means we need several reverence cells, and the intercept conveys the importance of all of them simultaneously. And when we have numerical features to boot, that complicates things even further. Your link mentions that the alternative is dropping the intercept, which will allow all dummy feature parameters to convey importance directly. But my concern is, what will happen to importance of numeric features then? They need the intercept, don't they?

Comment: Looks like so far the answer to my question appears to be "Yes, it does make sense to drop one dummy feature to make the parameters interpretable, but their interpretation is still not going to be straightforward, as the importance is relative to the intercept. If interpretability is important, then a better solution would be dropping the intercept. If interpretability is **not** important, however, then it doesn't matter what we drop, if we drop anything at all - the model's performance is supposed to stay the same." Does that sound about right?